# An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the CreateEnvironment operation: Tag key 'Name' is reserved

Tags: jenkins, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

Im receiving following error when trying to deploy spring boot application using Jenkins to AWS Elastic beanstalk. This used to get deployed without an issue, but this error has started to occur recently.

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the CreateEnvironment operation: Tag key 'Name' is reserved and can't be modified.
```

Below is the configurations used to setup the cloudformation stack.

```
[
    {
      "OptionName": "ELBSubnets",
      "Namespace": "aws:ec2:vpc",
      "ExportName": "apis-nonprod-vpc-apis-sit-vpc::PublicSubnets"
    },
    {
      "OptionName": "Subnets",
      "ResourceName": "AWSEBAutoScalingGroup",
      "Namespace": "aws:ec2:vpc",
      "ExportName": "apis-nonprod-vpc-apis-sit-vpc::PrivateSubnets"
    },
    {
      "OptionName": "VPCId",
      "ResourceName": "AWSEBLoadBalancerSecurityGroup",
      "Namespace": "aws:ec2:vpc",
      "ExportName": "apis-nonprod-vpc-apis-sit-vpc::VpcId"
    },
    {
      "OptionName": "EC2KeyName",
      "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration",
      "Value": "develop-apis-sit"
    },
    {
      "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:customoption",
      "OptionName": "SecretBucket",
      "Value": "apis-sit-secrets"
    },
    {
      "OptionName": "spring.profiles.active",
      "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment",
      "Value": "sit"
    },
    {
      "OptionName": "IamInstanceProfile",
      "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration",
      "ExportName": "app-dev::EbsInstanceIamInstanceProfileName"
    },
    {
      "OptionName": "SSMParameterNamespace",
      "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:customoption",
      "Value": "app-dev"
    },
    {
      "OptionName": "BatchSize",
      "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:command",
      "Value": "1"
    },
    {
      "OptionName": "AppDynamicsAgentBucket",
      "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:customoption",
      "Value": "appdynamics-agents-nonprod"
    }
]
```

Comment: `Name` is one of the few tags that Elastic Beanstalk applies by default to your environment and you can't edit these default tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Name` is one of the few tags that Elastic Beanstalk applies by default to your environment and you can't edit these default tags.

From [AWS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.tagging.html):

> Elastic Beanstalk applies environment tags to the environment resource
> itself, as well as to other AWS resources that Elastic Beanstalk
> creates for the environment.
>
> By default, Elastic Beanstalk applies a few tags to your environment:
>
> - `elasticbeanstalk:environment-name` – The name of the environment.
> - `elasticbeanstalk:environment-id` – The environment ID.
> - `Name` – Also the name of the environment. `Name` is used in the Amazon EC2 dashboard to identify and sort resources.
>
> **You can't edit these default tags.**